# Android performance in searching a specific word from a txt file

Tags: android, performance, search, dictionary, text-files

I am creating a dictionary that consist of about 100, 000 words and those words will be stored in a txt file. May I know if I read a txt file and store each word into the arrayList and then use binary search to search for a particular word, will it affect the performance of the android application? Or are there any better solution to enhance/optimize the word search in a txt file for android?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it on the UI thread, then yes, it will have an effect on the performance of your application, especially if the user has an older device. Specifically, your app will ANR for the time it takes you to finish the search.

If you do it on a background thread (using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)* for example), it will not have an effect on how responsive the app will be. However, background threads are typically with lower priority, so the search will take a bit longer. And of course, if the device your app is running on is an older single core device, your main app will feel a bit sluggish, as the CPU will be shared between the two threads.

As far as the actual algorithm for searching the word, binary search is not terribly bad. However, a little bit of indexing would help a lot to speed your search. When you are loading the list of words in the array, create also a simple index for each alphabet letter that points to the first word that starts with it. This way the operation to narrow the binary search range substantially will O(1). Technically this does not change the theoretical performance of the algorithm (you are still bound by the binary search O(log n)), but in practice it will have immediate effect on the actual performance.

On a side note, I have written a simple word solver app that does a linear word search on a background thread and on modern devices (Galaxy Nexus or Nexus 7) even that approach is ok, and allows me to update the search results with relatively good speed as the user types. So it all depends on how often you have to perform the search.

- `AsyncTask` has its own problems, so use it to bootstrap your code only, but switch to a better solution as soon as possible once you nail your main logic.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am sorry I am still a beginner .May I know how to create a simple index for each alphabet letter ? Is it something like creating 2 arraylist where one store the index and the other stores the words?

Comment: @Franci Penov, what is better than AsyncTask?  I found a major flaw with it last night for API 8.  I had the same problems trying to do the same thing using a Thread and Runnable class.  Thanks!

Comment: @RickFalck just use your own scheduler and schedule `Runnable` on it.

Comment: @AuroraBlaze make a map of char to index in the array list.

Comment: @FranciPenov , thank you very much for the explanations and guides. I appreciate it. =)